# How does "MasterChef (V2/3)" work in terms of rewards? What does it reward to a provider?

Tags: tokens, uniswap, liquidity-provider, reward, sushiswap

Talking about Sushiswap, Uniswap and similar projects:

Suppose, I've deposited tokenA and tokenB into a liquidity pool and received "TokenAB LP" tokens.

When I send my "TokenAB LP" to MasterChef (V2/3) for Yield Farming, in form will I then be getting rewards? Will it be as "TokenAB LP" tokens too? Or yet other special token? Does that depend a on DEX?